# Call jsonb_contains function (postgres) using JPA criteria and JsonBinaryType

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, jsonb, criteria-api

I have a JPA/Hibernate entity which has a JSONB column (using https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types ) for storing a list of strings. This works fine so far.

```
@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
```

```
@Type(type = "jsonb")
@Column(name = "TAGS", columnDefinition = "jsonb")
private List<String> tags;
```

Now I want to check if another string is contained in the list of strings.

I *can* do this by writing a native query and use the `@>` operator from Postgres. Because of other reasons (the query is more complex) I do not want to go in that direction. My current approach is calling the `jsonb_contains` method in a Spring Data specification ([since the operator is just alias to this function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55647306/how-to-convert-psqls-json-json-to-a-jpa-jpql-predicate/55647971#55647971)), e.g. `jsonb_contains('["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]','["tag1"]')`. What I am struggling with is, getting the second parameter right.

My initial approach is to also use a List of Strings.

```
    public static Specification<MyEntity> hasTag(String tag) {
        return (root, query, cb) -> {
            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(tag)) {
                return criteriaBuilder.conjunction();
            }
            Expression<Boolean> expression = criteriaBuilder.function("jsonb_contains",
                                                                      Boolean.class,
                                                                      root.get("tags"),
                                                                      criteriaBuilder.literal(List.of(tag)));
            return criteriaBuilder.isTrue(expression);
        };
    }
```

This results in the following error.

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function jsonb_contains(jsonb, character varying) does not exist
  Hinweis: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 375
```

It does know that `root.get("tags")` is mapped to JSONB but for the second parameter it does not. How can I get this right? Is this actually possible?

Answer (score 3):

`jsonb_contains(jsob, jsonb)` parameters must be `jsonb` type.

- You **can not** pass a Java `String` as a parameter to the function.
- You **can not** do casting in Postgresql via JPA Criteria.
- Using `JSONObject` or whatever **does not** help because Postgresql sees it as
  `bytea` type.

There are 2 possible solutions:

### Solution 1

Create `jsonb` with `jsonb_build_object(text[])` function and send it to `jsonb_contains(jsonb, jsonb)` function:

```
   public static Specification<MyEntity> hasTag(String tag) {
            
            // get List of key-value: [key1, value1, key2, value2...]
            List<Object> tags = List.of(tag);
            
            // create jsonb from array list
            Expression<?> jsonb = criteriaBuilder.function(
                    "jsonb_build_object",
                    Object.class,
                    cb.literal(tags)
            );

            Expression<Boolean> expression = criteriaBuilder.function(
                    "jsonb_contains",
                    Boolean.class,
                    root.get("tags"),
                    jsonb
            );

            return criteriaBuilder.isTrue(expression);
    }
```

### Solution 2

Create custom function in your Postgresql and use it in Java:

SQL:

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION jsonb_contains_as_text(a jsonb, b text)
> RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
>   SELECT CASE
>   WHEN a @> b::jsonb THEN TRUE
>   ELSE FALSE
> END;$$
> LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE STRICT;
> ```

Java Code:

> ```
>    public static Specification<MyEntity> hasTag(String tag) {
>
>             Expression<Boolean> expression = criteriaBuilder.function(
>                    "jsonb_contains_as_text",
>                     Boolean.class,
>                     root.get("tags"),
>                     criteriaBuilder.literal(tag)
>             );
>
>             return criteriaBuilder.isTrue(expression);
>     }
> ```

Comment: Solution 1 for me worked with jsonb_build_array:      
criteriaBuilder.function(
                "jsonb_build_array",
                Any::class.java,
                *ids.map { criteriaBuilder.literal(it) }.toTypedArray()).   
Sorry it's in kotlin

Comment: @AndreiBardyshev thx for your answer, *ids.map { criteriaBuilder.literal(it) }.toTypedArray()) - this is the key for me) 
In hibernate 5 criteriaBuilder.literal(tag) - was enough

Answer (score 0):

I think that the reason is that you pass the `varchar` as the second param. `jsonb_contains()` requires two `jsonb` params.

To check a jsonb array contains all/any values from a string array you need to use another operators: `?&` or `?|`.

The methods bindings for them in PSQL 9.4 are: `jsonb_exists_all` and `jsonb_exists_any` correspondingly.

In your PSQL version, you could check it by the following command:

```
select * from pg_operator where oprname = '?&'
```